# Python ftplib - connecting through a proxy with custom port

Tags: python, proxy, ftplib

**My question then, is how do I modify the connection string to cater for the particulars that my firewall is expecting?**

This one is a little bit of a compound issue.

1. I am connecting from behind an enterprise proxy. I can successfully connect using Filezilla. More info below.
2. The proxy has a custom port through which I need to connect: `8021`.

I'm no ftplib guru, but this is what I have worked out so far:

```
    import ftplib
    from dateutil import parser
    
    host_proxy = 'our.proxy.internal'
    host_port = 8021
    
    ftp_user = 'username'
    ftp_pass = 'password'
    ftp_host = 'ftp.thesite.com'
    
    u = "user %s@%s" % (ftp_user, ftp_host)
    p = "pass %s" % (ftp_pass)
    
    print(u)
    print(p)
    
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(host_proxy, host_port, u, p)
```

This setup fails with an error: `ConnectionRefusedError No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

This is progress!

The Filezilla custom FTP proxy setup is as follows:

```
    user %u@%h 
    pass %p
```

Where:

```
%u = ftp_user   
%h = ftp_host   
%p = ftp_pass   
Proxy Host = our.proxy.internal
```

The split across 2 lines is important, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, for the scenario posted:

```
import ftplib
from dateutil import parser

#proxy details
host_proxy = 'organisation.silly.proxy'
host_port = 8021

#ftp details
ftp_user = 'ftpusername'
ftp_pass = 'ftppassword'
ftp_host = 'ftp.thesite.com'

ftp_loginstring = ftp_user + "@" + ftp_host 

ftp = FTP()
ftp.set_debuglevel(1)
ftp.connect(host_proxy, host_port)
ftp.login(user=ftp_loginstring, passwd=ftp_pass)


print("Logged in ok")
```